# Figure Captions contain lots of underscores

Tags: floats

I am using the following code to produce a document as in attachment. The problem is that latex does not begin with the new line in caption. Maybe because of _. Is there any way to fix the problem?

Thanks a lot!!

```
 \documentclass[obeyspaces,spaces,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
 \usepackage{caption}

 \captionsetup{aboveskip=6pt, format = hang, justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false, labelfont=bf} 

 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[H]

 \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}

 \begin{picture}(16.5,12.3773)
 \put(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=0.25798]{io_dme_PDFs/00000000005_ADC.pdf}}
 \end{picture}

 \caption{\small io\_dme/IO\_DME/HardwareInterface/HWI/ADC\_io\_dme/IO\_DME/HardwareInterface/MappingToHardware/DIG\_OUT/DS2211\_02\_07\_DIG[0\textbar 1]\_io\_dme/IO\_DME/HardwareInterface/MappingToHardware/DIG\_OUT/DS2211\_02\_07\_DIG[0\textbar 1]}
 \label{iodme/IODME/HardwareInterface/HWI/ADC}

 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image: caption with lot of _]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The `caption` of a figure or table is generally meant to be human-readable and provide an overview of what the figure or table is about. Your caption currently doesn't have much of a chance of meeting either objective. Can you come up with an easier-to-read caption? (Coming up with a simpler `\label` would also be a good idea.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compiles fine for me

```
\documentclass[obeyspaces,spaces,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
 \usepackage{caption}

 \captionsetup{aboveskip=6pt, format = hang, justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false, labelfont=bf} 

\usepackage{url}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}

 \caption{\protect\path{io_dme/IO_DME/HardwareInterface/HWI/ADC_io_dme/IO_DME/HardwareInterface/MappingToHardware/DIG_OUT/DS2211_02_07_DIG[0|1]_io_dme/IO_DME/HardwareInterface/MappingToHardware/DIG_OUT/DS2211_02_07_DIG[0|1]}}
 \label{iodme/IODME/HardwareInterface/HWI/ADC}

 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really like your solution. but the only problem is the font type, can I still change it? I tried it but didnt work :(.

Comment: See the url package manual, however for readability I think it is better to let it stand out

Answer (score 0):

No one can read such a caption. You can cut it by hand :

```
 \caption{\small io\_dme/IO\_DME/HardwareInterface/HWI/ADC\_io\_dme/IO\_DME/\\HardwareInterface/MappingToHardware/DIG\_OUT/\\DS2211\_02\_07\_DIG[0\textbar 1]\_io\_dme/IO\_DME/HardwareInterface/\\MappingToHardware/DIG\_OUT/DS2211\_02\_07\_DIG[0\textbar 1]}
```

But the best should be to make an hyperlink.[image]

Comment: Actually the problem is that the Tex file will be generated automaticall through Matlab Code for a very huge document.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX as far as I can tell doesn't break automatically on the '/' character. However, you can insert `\allowbreak` commands to (surprise!) allow LaTeX to break at the specified points. For example,

```
\caption[short caption]{\small io\_dme/\allowbreak{}IO\_DME/\allowbreak{}HardwareInterface/\allowbreak{}HWI/\allowbreak{}ADC\_io\_dme/\allowbreak{}IO\_DME/\allowbreak{}HardwareInterface/\allowbreak{}MappingToHardware/\allowbreak{}DIG\_OUT/\allowbreak{}DS2211\_02\_07\_DIG[0\textbar 1]\_io\_dme/\allowbreak{}IO\_DME/\allowbreak{}HardwareInterface/\allowbreak{}MappingToHardware/\allowbreak{}DIG\_OUT/\allowbreak{}DS2211\_02\_07\_DIG[0\textbar 1]}
```

will tell LaTeX to automatically break your text at appropriate positions.

Note that for some reason you need to specify the `[short caption]` parameter, too, otherwise LaTeX complains. I'm not sure why this is the case.